# using prepared statments with MYSQL http plugin

Tags: mysql, http, prepared-statement

I am interested in using the MySQL HTTP plugin, using the sql endpoint to execute arbitrary sql via a web request.  However, is there any way to used prepared statements with the HTTP plugin sql endpoint?  I can't seem to find any information about this

This is MySQL http plugin :  https://scriptingmysql.wordpress.com/2015/01/15/mysql-5-7-labs-and-the-http-plugin-inserting-updating-and-deleting-records-in-mysql-via-http/

Comment: Which particular one?

Comment: @tadman question is edited to reflect which http plugin I am referring to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like for now the answer is no. From the documentation:

> The HTTP SQL endpoint does not support prepared statements. Prepared statements prepare a statement once, then allow multiple executions. For this, a client sends a statement to the server to be prepared. The server replies with a handle for the prepared statement. Then, the client sends parameter values for bound parameters, if any, before the statement gets executed. This prepared statement protocol requires session support, which is not available.

The documentation seems to be provided only as a PDF file, so that's highly annoying, but you can download it from the [Labs site](https://labs.mysql.com).